# Does every triangle-free graph with maximum degree at most 6 have a 5-colouring?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, co.combinatorics

### A very specific case of Reed's Conjecture

Reed's $\omega$,$\Delta$, $\chi$ conjecture proposes that every graph has $\chi \leq \lceil \tfrac 12(\Delta+1+\omega)\rceil$.  Here $\chi$ is the chromatic number, $\Delta$ is the maximum degree, and $\omega$ is the clique number.

When restricted to triangle-free graphs, the equivalent question is, Does every triangle-free graph have chromatic number $\leq \frac \Delta 2 +2$?

This is known for $\Delta\leq 4$.  In general for triangle-free graphs, $\chi \leq O(\Delta/\log \Delta)$, so the conjecture is also true for very large $\Delta$.

How about $\Delta=5$?  $\Delta=6$?  Because of parity, $\Delta=6$ is the easier of these two cases (and actually easily implies the $\Delta=5$ case.  Can anyone prove it?

Kostochka proved that every triangle-free graph has $\chi \leq \frac 2 3 \Delta +2$.  He also proved that $\chi\leq \frac \Delta 2 +2$ for graphs of sufficiently large girth depending on $\Delta$.  Can anyone prove it for girth $\geq 5$? $4$?

This would at least provide some hope for proving Reed's Conjecture for triangle-free graphs.

> Does every triangle-free graph with $\Delta\leq 6$ have $\chi \leq 5$?  What about every graph with girth at least five?

Comment: This is not addressing your question, but I wonder if it is
known whether Reed's conjecture holds when $\chi$ is replaced
by $\chi_f$, the fractional chromatic number?

Comment: Good question; it is known to hold, without the round-up. Reed never published the result in a paper but it's in Graph Colouring and the Probabilistic Method (with Molloy), in the chapter on hard-core distributions (Chapter 23 I think). 

(It wouldn't let me comment twice in a row, so I deleted the old comment to add:  )

A proof of a stronger result, noted by McDiarmid, appears in Section 2.2 of my thesis, which is here: http://www.columbia.edu/~ak3074/papers/phdthesis.pdf

Comment: Another possible tangential attack is to establish the conjecture for the "warmth" $w$ of the graph, because Brightwell and Winkler proved that $w \le \chi$.